# How to generate a random layout in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I wanted to ask a question I couldnt find it for many months. Now in Android Studio inside my "activity_main", I made about 15 layouts. Now what I want that with a button clicked I want a code "in Java" to show up a random layout from the 15 layouts.

Look please at the example down below.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapters);
        
        layout1 = findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout2 = findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout3 = findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        layout4 = findViewById(R.id.layout4);
        
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // code to choose a random layout
            }
        });
```

Please I will appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried implementing any solutions to your problem? any bugs or output from those solutions?

Comment: I tried but there was bug so I need help